# macos llvm-symbolizer not found

Tags: macos, clang, llvm

I am trying to use address sanitization when calling my program with clang, however it doesn't seem to be installed. If I type `which llvm-symbolizer` I get `llvm-symbolizer not found`. I also checked under `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` and under the location where clang is installed `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin` but still I can't find llvm-symbolizer (though there are other llvm-* executables in the last path).

Is there a way I can install this on macos? Also, I couldn't find it in brew. I am using clang built in macos: `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My version of *llvm-symbolizer* was installed with Homebrew. You have to install *llvm* with *brew install llvm* to get it. It then shows up as:

```
% which llvm-symbolizer
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/11.0.0/bin/llvm-symbolizer
```

Comment: Thanks @Olsonist, I didn't search for llvm by itself. It worked now.

Answer (score 5):

By the way, some people may have installed llvm but not linked some binaries to path. The sure-fire way to add all llvm binaries to path is:

```sh
PATH="$PATH:$(brew --prefix)/opt/llvm/bin"
```

`$(brew --prefix)/opt/llvm` is a symbolic link to the most recent installed version of `llvm`, and `bin` is obviously the binaries therein.